# Induction proof giving false results. $(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$ and for every $x\geq -1$ in $\mathbb R$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction

It can be proven for induction that $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb N$ and for all real numbers $x>-1$. I was doing this exercise, and there was an error in the text, the text said: for all $|x|>1$, which is false. I noticed it was false because i solved algebrically a particular case in which $n=3$. What if i didn't notice it? At the point of the proof $(1+x)(1+x)^n\geq 1+(n+1)x+nx^2$ i would have written it was true because $1+(n+1)x+nx^2\geq 1+(n+1)x$. So in that case assuming the text was saying somenthing true i wouldn't have notice i have proven something false. In this case i have that a false statement implies a false statement which is true for its logic table.
My questions are:

1. generally when you prove something for induction you have an expression you don't know where it comes from, it could be a result you have guessed by observing the behavior of preceeding cases. How can you be sure that you are not demonstrating something false if the induction proof conclusion is not evidently false like in the example given above?
2. in the example given where does $1+nx$ comes from? Is it the "biggest" curve of first grade for which the property of being less or equal to $(1+x)^n$ is true? If yes, how have you algebrically obtained this result?
3. how could i find algebrically the result that only $x\geq -1$ are solutions for $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For 3. it is not mandatory, if $n$ even it is true for all $x$ and if $n$ odd there is an intersection point that gets closer to $x=-2$ as $n$ increases, just $x>-1$ is a "safe" interval for this inequality.

Comment: A hint for your induction step: when you multiply $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$ by $1+x$, what is the sign of $1+x$ ?
The theorem doesn't say it's false for every $x\le-1$, just that it's not always true ;-)